# JQuery div tag has children in FireFox but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am using JQuery ajax to load images from a url, display them, and then place a button on top of each image.

The code works in firefox, but in chrome, the div parent "photos" that should have all the children(one child div "photo" for each image received from the url) is 0.

I have tried `read()` and `load()`, but nothing seems to work. If I run  `alert($('#photos').children().size());` in the Chrome console it returns the children. But at execution it returns 0. Any ideas?

```
$(window).load(function ()        
{
$("p").text("The DOM is now loaded and can be manipulated.");

 //returns 0 in chrome, but 10 in firefox
 alert($('#photos').children().size());

$('#photos').children().each(function() 
{   
//do stuff
```

Comment: Can you also add your HTML where the div is?

Comment: You should use property .length instead: alert($('#photos').children().length);  If not working, you have an error in your HTML, surely a missing closing tag

Comment: roasted is right: Sounds like your markup is messed up and somehow FF is more foregiving than Chrome.

Comment: I am a little confused. I examined the final markup of Firefox's html. It looks like the following.

    <div id="photos">
    <div id="blahblah.jpg" class="photo">
    <img src="blahblah.jpg">
    <div class="zoom" style="font-size: 48px;">
    </div>

As you can see, the JQuery code "$('#photos').children().each(function() " actually had children to loop through, and so it inserted elements into it. Whereas, the chrome code does not loop through it at all. I am a little confused as to what the length property has to do with anything.  Thanks.

Comment: One more important thing to emphasize is that the JQuery code "$('#photos').children()" in Chrome returns 0 at execution, but returns 10 when run in the Chrome Console. So it seems like the DOM isn't fully loaded, but then I don't know how load() could be called without all the elements on the page being added.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. For some reason, the local chrome server wasn't running, so therefor the javascript wasn't being executed at the right time it seems. Thanks.

Comment: It worked for a little bit, the same way it did in firefox, but then when I cleared the cookies in chrome, the image buttons never returned again. This is really weird. Any ideas?

Comment: Also, it doesn't work in IE either. Only firefox.

Comment: Deducing it more,  $(window).load(function ()   gets executed in firefox, but never in chrome. Why would this be?

Comment: Final solution. It had to do with ajax. All you have to do is set a timeout before your script runs to give the ajax time.